# Python. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: string, python-3.x, attributes

I have got this error when I try to run my program:

> C:\Users\Goldsmitd\chess\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:/Users/Goldsmitd/PycharmProjects/CHESS/chess_ver0.07.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Goldsmitd/PycharmProjects/CHESS/chess_ver0.07.py", line 138,
>   in 
>       a.display()   File "C:/Users/Goldsmitd/PycharmProjects/CHESS/chess_ver0.07.py", line 80,
>   in display
>       if self.board[i][j].sl=='R': AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sl'

Someone know what I do wrong?

```
__author__ = 'Goldsmitd'

class Rook:
    def __init__(self,x,y,sl,team):
        self.name = 'Rook'
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sl = sl
        self.team = team


class Knight:
    def __init__(self,x,y,sl,team):
        self.name = 'Knight'
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sl = sl
        self.team = team


class Bishop:
    def __init__(self,x,y,sl,team):
        self.name = 'Bishop'
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sl = sl
        self.team = team


class Queen:
    def __init__(self,x,y,sl,team):
        self.name = 'Queen'
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sl = sl
        self.team = team


class King:
    def __init__(self,x,y,sl,team):
        self.name = 'King'
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sl = sl
        self.team = team


class Pawn:
    def __init__(self,x,y,sl,team):
        self.name = 'Pawn'
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sl = sl
        self.team = team


class Chess_Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [['.']*8 for _ in range(8)]
        self.board[7][0] = Rook(x=7,y=0,sl='R',team='white')
        self.board[7][1] = Knight(x=7,y=1,sl='N',team='white')
        self.board[7][2] = Bishop(x=7,y=2,sl='B',team='white')
        self.board[7][3] = Queen(x=7,y=3,sl='Q',team='white')
        self.board[7][4] = King(x=7,y=4,sl='K',team='white')
        self.board[7][5] = Bishop(x=7,y=5,sl='B',team='white')
        self.board[7][6] = Knight(x=7,y=6,sl='N',team='white')
        self.board[7][7] = Rook(x=7,y=7,sl='R',team='white')
        self.board[6][0] = Pawn(x=6,y=0,sl='P',team='white')
        self.board[6][0] = Pawn(x=6,y=1,sl='P',team='white')
        self.board[6][0] = Pawn(x=6,y=2,sl='P',team='white')
        self.board[6][0] = Pawn(x=6,y=3,sl='P',team='white')
        self.board[6][0] = Pawn(x=6,y=4,sl='P',team='white')
        self.board[6][0] = Pawn(x=6,y=5,sl='P',team='white')
        self.board[6][0] = Pawn(x=6,y=6,sl='P',team='white')
        self.board[6][0] = Pawn(x=6,y=7,sl='P',team='white')

    def display(self):
        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                if self.board[i][j].sl=='R':
                    print('R',end=' ')
                elif self.board[i][j].sl=='N':
                    print('N',end=' ')
                elif self.board[i][j].sl=='B':
                    print('B',end=' ')
                elif self.board[i][j].sl=='Q':
                    print('Q',end=' ')
                elif self.board[i][j].sl=='K':
                    print('K',end=' ')
                elif self.board[i][j].sl=='P':
                    print('P',end=' ')
                else:
                    print(self.board[i][j],end=' ')
            print()

    def figure_choice(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print('please give a position of figure which you chose')
                sx=int(input())
                sy=int(input())
                return sx,sy
            except:
                print('ERROR. Your choice is valid. Please choose only integers')

    def move_king(self):

        while True:
            try:
                print('please give a position of figure which you chose')
                sx=int(input())
                sy=int(input())
                return sx,sy
            except:
                print('ERROR. Your choice is valid. Please choose only integers')
            try:
                print('please give a position of king')
                sx=int(input())
                sy=int(input())
            except:
                print('ERROR. Your choice is valid. Please choose only integers')
            try:
                print('please choose a destination for king')
                dx=int(input())
                dy=int(input())
            except:
                print('ERROR. Your choice is valid. Please choose only integers')
            if self.board[dx][dy] == '.' :
                    if ( abs(sx-dx) <2 and abs(sx-dy) < 2 ):
                        self.board[dx][dy]=King(x=dx,y=dy,sl='K',team='white')
                        self.board[sx][sy] = '.'
                        return self.board
                        break


a=Chess_Board()

a.display()
print(a.board[7][0].sl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

```
self.board = [['.']*8 for _ in range(8)]
```

for some values of `i` and `j`, `self.board[i][j]` is a string. Therefore,

```
self.board[i][j].sl=='R'
```

is raising `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sl'` because strings have no `sl` attribute.

---

Perhaps the easiest way to fix your code with minimal changes would be to add an `Empty` class similar to other chess piece classes to represent unoccupied squares on the chess board. Make sure instances of the `Empty` class have an `sl` attribute.

Note however that it is not clear (to me) that you really need separate classes
for each kind of chess piece. They are all basically the same *kind* of object,
they merely differ in terms of how they move. So you may be better off with *one
chess piece class* and give each instance a `kind` attribute which could equal
`'rook'`, `'knight'`, etc.

Also note that in your code there is redundant information: The `self.board` records the location of the pieces, and the chess piece also records the location:

```
    self.board[7][0] = Rook(x=7,y=0,sl='R',team='white')
```

Recording the information in two places poses a problem:

- The information may become corrupted -- if the logic in your code is not correct, the board may record the location of a piece in a different place than where the piece itself thinks it is on the board. Thus you have a coordination problem.
- Having the information in two places makes your code more complicated because you have to update the location in both the board and the chess piece to maintain consistency every time a piece is moved.

Comment: Ok, I know what do I do. I have to create board which all elements are instances of classes. So empty squares without figures must also be a class.